# link issue with whole-archive & no-whole_archive options

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, static-libraries

I tried to use `-whole-archive`/`-no-whole-archive` options for linking. The gcc is 4.1.2. when I try:

```
g++ ...... -Wl, -whole-archive libA.a -Wl, -no-whole-archive libB.a ...
```

It says `-whole-archive` and `-no-whole-archive` are unrecognized.
When I replace `-whole-archive` with `--whole-archive`, and same to `no-whole-archive`, it says

```
error: unrecognized command line option "-fwhole-archive"
error: unrecognized command line option "-fno-whole-archive"
```

Does anyone know where the problem comes from?

Comment: Because those options aren't supported on your (ancient) version of the compiler and linker? Check the version of the linker (the `ld` program) and read [the online documentation](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.23.1/) for that version.

Comment: Actually my ld has the option, but there should be no space between -Wl, and -whole-archive. Weird world.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried using the following syntax?

```
-Wl,--whole-archive
```

I.e., no space after the comma and two dashes.